# Completely reset Mojave disk

Tags: macos, disk-utility, apfs

I’ve got a Mojave installation with an APFS drive. I’ve installed and uninstalled Boot Camp partitions several times over the years, and somehow things have gotten out of sync. I can now see the 500GB drive in Disk Utility, but there is only a single 300GB APFS container, and Boot Camp Assistant is giving me some errors when I try to repartition the drive.

I’m due to reinstall macOS from scratch anyway for some other reasons, so I’d like to completely destroy the disk (including all of the APFS containers and volumes) and have it reinitialized back as if it was a freshly out—of-the-box machine.

If I reboot into Recovery Mode and use Disk Utility, is there a way I can delete and then recreate all of the disk configuration?

Answer (score 1):

### Doing a clean install over the Internet

Hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys at startup to boot to internet recovery. After booting to recovery mode, use the Disk Utility to erase the drive. Choose the APFS format.

### Doing a clean install using a flash drive

You can also choose to download Mojave from the App Store. You can then [transfer the installer to a flash drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Afterwards, restart the Mac and hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key until the Startup Manager icons appear. Choose to boot from the flash drive. Use the Disk Utility to erase the drive. Choose the APFS format.